# Split words and numbers from tags python

Tags: python, split

I have a sentence: "Am/V I/NN good/Adj enough/Prep for/Prep 1/2/NUM" and I have to split into words and tags and create two different dictionaries - for words and for tags. I saw a thread here but there wasn't a word about splitting this thing - 1/2/NUM.

So I suppose I have to do something like this:

```
s = "Am/V I/NN good/Prep enough/Prep for/Prep 1/2/NUM"
sent = s.split()
for word in sent:
    word = word.split('/[a-z]')
dict_of_words = list(words[0])
doct_of_tags = list(words[1])
```

but then I get this:

```
['Am/'V]
['I/NN']
[good/Prep]
etc.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What is your expected output for this input?

Comment: Those aren't dictionaries and it is bad style to name something like `dict_...` if it is not a dict.

Comment: I'd like to get a list of words and list of tags for the output

Answer (score 3):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the spaces first:

```
s = "Am/V I/NN good/Prep enough/Prep for/Prep 1/2/NUM"
sent = s.split()
```

Then for each item [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) on the `/` character:

```
for item in sent:
    data = item.rsplit('/', 1)
    word = data[0]
    tag = data[1]
```

Or if you prefer more concise code:

```
for item in sent:
    word, tag = item.rsplit('/', 1)
```

Comment: @Repzz Another item worth noting is that in your example you're trying to split on multiple characters, which you can't do, and using a regex in the string split method. To split on multiple characters, regex is the right choice, but you need `import re` and `re.split(r'/', words)` for example.

Comment: @binarysubstrate perhaps make that an answer?

Comment: @shuttle87 I didn't want to step on your answer, but sure I'll post it.

Comment: @binarysubstrate thank you! But with these method I don't get 1/2 as one and with shuttle87-method I get it

Comment: @Repzz Take a look at the answer I just posted; that should help if you ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments on shuttle87's answer, here is a simple example showing split with regex in case you need to split on multiple characters, which you can't do with the string split method.

```
import re

s = "Am/V I/NN good/Prep enough/Prep for/Prep 1/2/NUM"

parts = s.split(" ")
words_tags = [re.split(r'/(?=[A-Za-z])', part) for part in parts]

words = []
tags = []
for word_tag in words_tags:
    words.append(word_tag[0])
    tags.append(word_tag[1])
```

> ['Am', 'I', 'good', 'enough', 'for', '1/2']
>   ['V', 'NN', 'Prep', 'Prep', 'Prep', 'NUM']

[Regex demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/jW1aE9/1)

Comment: Thank you! I need to get 1/2 from "1/2/NUM" adn I can't get it using re.strip

Comment: @Repzz that's no problem. You just need to update the regex to `/(?=[A-Za-])`. I've updated my answer to produce the desired output. When you post a question again, it's helpful if you also indicate the desired output.  :-)